# We need a name for our secondary chat room

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Now that we have a new name for our primary chat room, [The Classroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174), we need a name for the permanent [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60468) we have for helping users refine questions.

This is where we can direct users, especially users new to the Stack Exchange Network, when we find a question that is a good question, but not a good post. As we discuss the question with the user, we can guide them in creating a quality post that increases their potential for quality answers.

This was already discussed and a few suggested accumulated in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/conversation/room-naming) while discussing the main room's name.

Vote on the answer below that you think is the best name. If none are what you like, then answer with your own suggestion and it can be voted on with the rest.

Once our community has voted enough, our moderators can rename that room for us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the purpose of the room is to offer guidance to users when they need it, and a scholastic environment theme is developing for our site, I suggest that we name this room the [Guidance Office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60468).

Comment: It also goes well with the super secret name of the mod room, "The Principal's Office".  But you didn't hear that from me!

Comment: @BenI. We wouldn't want that anyway. The users aren't _in trouble_, the just need a guiding hand.